# Resumable File Upload in Google API Ver 2

Tags: c#, upload, large-files, google-docs

I am trying to upload large file on Google Docs.
And i came across [Resumable Upload](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ResumableUpload).

But how can i implement it in Google API Ver 2 ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

From what I read on the V2 and V3 docs for the API, V2 does not support resumable uploads. You would have to manually handle the upload based on the specs of the v3 docs. Meaning you would have to send the http request to the server, along with all the expected headers, and the content body if needed.